# fancybox - how can I put a link from the opened image?

Tags: jquery, image, hyperlink, fancybox

-largeAny Ideas folks? I'm trying to link the opened image in fancybox.
I've looked everywhere! It sounds so simple...

So here's the code I'm using:

```
<a id="manual1" href="javascript:;"><img src="/example-thumb.png" alt="example" /></a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Cms_Data/Sites/Base/Files/js/fancyboxV2.1.0/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#manual1").click(function() {
$.fancybox([
    '/example-large.jpg',
    '/example-large2.jpg',
    {
        'href'  : '/example-large3.jpg',
        'title' : 'Lorem ipsum '
    }
    ], {
        padding : 38,
        nextEffect : 'fade',
        prevEffect : 'fade'
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: a small syntax error is the `,` after the image file

Comment: link to what? you want to have a link on the fancybox image? you could bind the click event when fancybox use the callback `afterShow`  or `afterLoad` and then bind the image displayed by fancybox.

Comment: @JonT, make sure that jQuery is also included before the fancybox plugin, and that the paths are correct..

Comment: Hi Gaby & Voigtan, I have more images after '/example-large.jpg', hence the ,
I need the image ('/example-large.jpg') to link to a url
Aye forgot to include the JQuery in the above code
apologies Voigtan I'm a complete novice to jQ/js I'm a lowely designer :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Im still not sure what you are after but is if when you click on the anchor you could do two things:
etiher you find the image and its src and replace -thumb to -full and use that to trigger your fancybox method, or you could use html5 data attribute and tell what image url you want:

```
<a id="manual1" data-image="/example-full.jpg,/example-full-2.jpg'><img src="/example-thumb.png" alt="example" /></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#manual1').click(function() {
    var data = $(this).data('images').split(','),
        options = {
            padding : 38,
            nextEffect : 'fade',
            prevEffect : 'fade',
            type: 'image'
        };
    $.fancybox.open(data , options );
})
 </script>
```

and a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/voigtan/jJpAM/2/

**Demo if you are using one image only**

```
$('.test').click(function() {
    var a = this,
        images = [],
        data = $(a).data('images').split(','),
        options = {
            padding : 38,
            nextEffect : 'fade',
            prevEffect : 'fade',
            type: 'image',
            afterShow: function() {
                $("img.fancybox-image").click(function() {
                    window.location.href = a.href;                        
                });
            }
        };
    $.fancybox.open(data , options );
    return false;
})
```

and another demo: http://jsfiddle.net/voigtan/jJpAM/3/

Comment: HI Voigtan, what I'm after is when the <a id="manual1"> is clicked the example-large is displayed in fancybox - the viewed example-large.jpg can then be clicked to go to a new page (ie surround example-large.jpg with an <a href="www.anotherpage.com">

Comment: you can´t do that, you have an array of images that will (by default CSS) and the arrows will be 50% of each side so you wont be able to click on it. if you dont have a gallery then my first idea that you bound the click event on the popup image.

Comment: hmmm damnit....maybe a future feature for fancybox if the arrows (left/right nav) were only 10% each side with the center being clickable

Comment: you could have a title and bind the click event on the title maybe? or change the CSS yourself? here is a new example http://jsfiddle.net/voigtan/jJpAM/3/ this is just one image now and if you click on it it will go to the `anchor` elements `href` url.

Comment: just looked on the code I was wrong the width on it is 40%, so you have a 20% area to click on.

Comment: hmm almost there! works fine on one image trouble is I'm calling an array of images <a id="manual1" href="javascript:;">

Comment: if you are using my code just add a comma `,` on your images see example: http://jsfiddle.net/voigtan/jJpAM/4/ if you can´t change your HTML markup then you will need to hardcode everything in the method instead.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21390/discussion-between-voigtan-and-jont)

Answer (score 4):

```
what I'm after is when the <a id="manual1"> is clicked the example-large is 
displayed in fancybox - the viewed example-large.jpg can then be clicked 
to go to a new page
```

Another simpler and cleaner approach, based on your code (the fancybox manual method) is to add a custom **link** option for each image, then use the `beforeShow` callback to wrap the image with an `<a>` and its corresponding **link** like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#manual1").click(function() {
        $.fancybox.open([
            {
            href: 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg',
            title: 'this image links to bbc news',
            link: 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/'},
        {
            href: 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg',
            title: 'this image links to jquery',
            link: 'http://jquery.com'},
        {
            href: 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg',
            title: 'this image links to fancybox',
            link: 'http://fancyapps.com'}
        ], {
            beforeShow: function() {
                $(".fancybox-image").wrap('<a href="' + this.link + '" />')
            },
            padding: 38,
            nextEffect: 'fade',
            prevEffect: 'fade'
        });
        return false;
    });
}); // ready
```

In this way you don't need to pass a long `data-` attribute in your html (no split needed either) and keep it as simple as :

```
<a id="manual1" href="javascript:;"><img src="/example-thumb.png" alt="example" /></a>
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w6p49/)**

**NOTICE** that in my demo, I changed the css properties of the navigation arrows to avoid overlapping with the linked image.

Comment: Hey, I know it's like a year later, but this is exactly what I needed.  The best part is I wanted simple HTML, and this definitely did that for me.  Did you create Fancybox or something because you answer tons of questions about it...?

Comment: @Keven : Oh no, fancybox is just my preferred jQuery plugin, it is well written and that is hard to find. I answer the questions because it's easy to me, just that (I've been using it for years now). All credits go to its sole creator Janis Skarnelis http://stackoverflow.com/users/486595/janis

Answer (score 1):

this more simple and short code

```
$.fancybox.open([
{
    href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg',
    link : 'http://jquery.com/'}
],{
    afterShow: function() {
    $(".fancybox-image").wrap('<a href="' + this.link + '" />')
        },   

    padding : 0   
});
```