# Is it possible to create links in each image of a gallery opened with Fancybox?

Tags: jquery, image, hyperlink, fancybox

I'm totally new to Fancybox.  I am trying to put different links in each image of a gallery opened with it.  I've done exactly what JFK has posted in [fancybox - how can I put a link from the opened image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953018/fancybox-how-can-i-put-a-link-from-the-opened-image).

It works, but I can only open the first image with Fancybox and then slide to others, but if I click directly on the second image or the third, Fancybox doesn't show up.

Here's my code:

```
<a id="manual1"  href="javascript:;"> <img src="images/04.png" width="58" height="174" /></a>
<a id="manual1" href="javascript:;"> <img src="images/03.png" width="58" height="174" /></a>    
<a id="manual1" href="javascript:;"> <img src="images/02.png" width="58" height="174" /></a>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#manual1").click(function() {
    $.fancybox.open([
        {
        href: 'images/yuangu.jpg',
        title: 'Haute',
        link: 'images/yuangubig.jpg'},
      {
        href: 'images/xianan01.jpg',
        title: 'Man in the Box',
        link: 'images/xianan01big.jpg'},
    {
        href: 'images/xianan02.jpg',
        title: 'Man in the Box 2',
        link: 'images/xianan02big.jpg'}
    ], {
        beforeShow: function() {
            $(".fancybox-image").wrap('<a href="' + this.link + '" />')
        },

        padding: 12,
        nextEffect: 'fade',
        prevEffect: 'fade'

    });
    return false;
}); 
}); // ready
```

Also, where should I add `target="_blank"` in order to open the links in a new window?

Thanks.

Comment: check this fiddle out http://jsfiddle.net/anVF5/

Comment: Read http://fancybox.net/faq No.7, this why only the first one works

Comment: `$(".fancybox-image").wrap('<a target="_blank" href="' + this.link + '" />')`